# SQL - SSRS Reports

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I am trying to report on staff anniversaries (either this month or the next month) by using a stored procedure and SSRS report builder.

The problem is if I select the parameter of the month or next month with the organization unit as 'All' it works, but if I select an individual organization unit, the report displays people who are not having a work anniversary (lists everyone on the database for that organization unit etc).

ON SSRS Report builder my Parameters are @month and @SelectList (in other words Organisation unit)

My Datasets is the main report stored procedure and SelectList.

The Selectlist basically breaks it down by the division then the region then section then cost group etc.

So am wondering how I can get the correct data displayed if I select a particular option from the select list?

I would greatly appreciate all assistance in this matter :)

My stored procedure code is below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[rpt_AnniversaryNextMonthTest](
@SelectList nvarchar(2000)
, @Month nvarchar(10)

)

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;


SELECT 
    DET_NUMBERA             as 'Emp ID'
    , DET_SURNAMEA          as 'Surname'    
    , DET_PREF_NMA          as 'Preferred Name'
    , DET_DATE_JNDD
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR, DET_DATE_JNDD, 103)          as 'Starting Date'
    , (CASE WHEN @Month= 'Next Month' AND Month(getdate())=12
            THEN DATEDIFF (year, (DET_DATE_JNDD), (getdate())) +1
            ELSE DATEDIFF (year, (DET_DATE_JNDD), (getdate()))
            END)    as 'Years of Service'

    , Division
    , Section
    , Pay_Location          as 'Location'
    , ReportsToName

FROM Current_Staff
WHERE POS_STATUSA NOT IN ('AA','AB','AC')
AND ((@Month= 'This Month' AND Month(DET_DATE_JNDD) = Month(Getdate()))
OR (@Month= 'Next Month' AND (Month(DET_DATE_JNDD) = Month(Getdate())+1 OR Month(Getdate())=12 AND Month(DET_DATE_JNDD)=1)))
AND (left(@SelectList,1)='0')
OR (left(@SelectList,1)='1' AND dbo.Current_Staff.Division=substring(@SelectList,2,50))
OR (left(@SelectList,1)='2' AND dbo.Current_Staff.Region=substring(@SelectList,2,50))
OR (left(@SelectList,1)='3' AND dbo.Current_Staff.Section=substring(@SelectList,2,50))
OR (left(@SelectList,1)='4' AND dbo.Current_Staff.CostGroup=substring(@SelectList,2,50))

END

GO
```

Comment: Just glancing, not tested but, I think you need to change `AND (left(@SelectList,1)='0')` to `AND ((left(@SelectList,1)='0')` and then add `)` at the end.

Comment: Is the @SelectList a multi select parameter from the report, or a single string field?

Comment: Hi all,
Thanks for the edits to make the code much clearer to read. Also Alan yes that was the case, it was as simple as the brackets! Jerry its a single select list. I amended the code to the following and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the edits to make the code much clearer to read. Also Alan yes that was the case, it was as simple as the brackets! Jerry its a single select list. I amended the code to the following and it worked. –

WHERE

((left(@SelectList,1)='0')
OR (left(@SelectList,1)='1' AND dbo.Current_Staff.Division=substring(@SelectList,2,50))
OR (left(@SelectList,1)='2' AND dbo.Current_Staff.Region=substring(@SelectList,2,50))
OR (left(@SelectList,1)='3' AND dbo.Current_Staff.Section=substring(@SelectList,2,50))
OR (left(@SelectList,1)='4' AND dbo.Current_Staff.CostGroup=substring(@SelectList,2,50)))

AND POS_STATUSA NOT IN ('AA','AB','AC')

AND ((@Month= 'This Month' AND Month(DET_DATE_JNDD) = Month(Getdate()))
OR (@Month= 'Next Month' AND (Month(DET_DATE_JNDD) = Month(Getdate())+1 OR Month(Getdate())=12 AND Month(DET_DATE_JNDD)=1)))

END